# Spring FlatFileItemReader - UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a batch job to synchronize some data once per day.
spring is used all over the project, right now i am experiencing an error
`org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader`

that is 
`Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException:${batch.reader.encoding.projectname}`

My question is now: what is the meaning of the (to me it looks like a qualifier) thing in the curly brackets? i cant seem to find the place where this is being set - it would help to see if there is something in it etc. since i essentially copied an already working batch job, so i am thinking that i just forgot to add my job to some xml config file?

thanks!

Comment: i know that this is scarce information, but i cant provide any more - confidential stuff, company policy etc. :S 
But an explanation on where this ${..} thing could be set (or usually is?) would already help a lot

Comment: it appears you don't have resource properties which contains the key ${batch.reader.encoding.projectname}

Comment: I found a config/properties file somewhere in the depths of the spring project folders.. should be the solution.

Comment: but the follow up question would be: how does spring know where to look for that from the key ${..} alone? is there some place where those property files are defined?

Comment: Search property-placeholder in spring configuration or you search '.properties' in xml files